# how to filter data in model forms according to fields in form in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to filter data according to selected fields in forms. I have created a model and imported it to forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Student_Detail, Student_Education
class StudentDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Student_Detail
       fields = ['name', 'surname' , 'sex', 'birth_date', 'area', 
          'state' ,
           'city' , 'pincode']

        def to_python(self, value):

            if not value:
                return []
            return value.split(',')
```

and my models are

`

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class State(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.state


class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey('State', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city


class Student_Detail(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    birth_date = models.DateTimeField()
    area = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey('State', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pincode = models.IntegerField()

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.surname`
```

Now I want to filter cities in form according to a state selected in the same form.

My View is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import City, Student_Detail, State, Student_Education
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import StudentDetailForm, StudentEducationForm


def get_student_data(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_detail = StudentDetailForm(request.POST)

        if form_detail.is_valid():
            form_detail.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')

    else:
        form_detail = StudentDetailForm()

        return render(request,'home/form.html/', 
        {'form_detail':form_detail, })

def thanks(request):
    template_name = 'home/thanks.html/'

    return render(request, template_name, {})
```

I am also trying to enter data in two different models using forms but some thing getting wrong while saving data in two different models at view layer.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Access your form fields like this `myForm.fields['name']` and filter Student_Detail

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def student_view(request):
    # your business logic or whatever goes here
    if form.is_valid():
        students = Student_Detail.objects.filter(name=myForm.fields['name'], 
                                           surname=myForm.fields['surname'])

    return render(request, 'student_view.html', {data=students})
```